# Splitting a summation and bounding it from below

Tags: calculus, summation

> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=1}^nk&=\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}k+\sum_{k=n/2+1}^nk\\
> &\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}0+\sum_{k=n/2+1}^n(n/2)\\
> &=(n/2)^2\\
> &=\Omega(n^2)
> \end{align}

I'm unable to understand why in the picture [see above] it shows that sigma lower bound $k=1$ and upper bound $n/2$ for $k=0$.

First time here please go easy on me.

Thank you

Comment: $k$ is never $0$, they use $k\geq 0$

Comment: Sum of zeroes is smaller then sum of something positive.

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: @vrug got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first sum: $1\leq k \leq n/2 \implies k >0$ so each term is individually greater than zero and hence the sum is greater than the sum where you replace each term by zero.

Second sum: same argument but $n/2+1 \leq k \leq n \implies k >n/2$.